# Factor $\frac{x^4 - 9x^2 + 4x + 12}{x - 2}$ using difference of cubes formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

This is  a problem I found from Lara Alcock's *How to Think About Analysis* (page 161) and I've been stumped for a while. So far I have tried to factor by grouping like so:
$\displaystyle\frac{x^4 - 9x^2 + 4x + 12}{x - 2}$

First considering the numerator:

$x^4 - 9x^2 + 4x + 12$

$= x^2(x^2 - 3^2) + 4(x + 3)$

$= x^2(x-3)(x+3) + 4(x+3)$

I've also tried rewriting the numerator to get a difference of cubes I could factor but haven't had much success. I would also love any recommendations for books/resources to practice more algebra problems like this. This is my first post, any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: The problem is basically telling you that $x=2$ is a root, and you found another one $x=-3$. See what's left after you divide by $(x-2)(x+3)$.

Comment: contrast with https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor+x%5E4-9x%5E2%2B4x%2B12+over+x-2

Comment: What is the numerator? $x^4 - 9x^2 + 4x + 12$ or  $x^4 - 2x^3 + 8x^2 + 14x + 7$?

Comment: Using cubes is mandatory from the book or is a way you are guessing for?

Comment: Fixed a typo in the numerator. The book asks the reader to attempt to simplify the problem using the difference of cubes formula as a challenge rather than immediately going for long division. Though I find it has been much easier to divide the polynomial by x-2 first and *then* use the difference of cubes formula.

Comment: @Jalapeñocakes Ah ok, I tought it was your own idea!

Comment: @Jalapeñocakes $\;\pm 12$ is neither a cube nor a difference of cubes over the integers, so you won't be able to write the original numerator as a difference of two "nice" cubes. Even if you divide by $x-2$ first, the constant term of the quotient will be $-6$, and that's neither a cube nor a difference of cubes, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since for the numerator $N(2)=0$ an effective way could be starting from

$$N(x) =x^4 - 9x^2 + 4x + 12 =(x^4 - 8x^2+16)-(x^2- 4x + 4)$$

A way to use difference of cubes formula could be as follows

$$x^4 - 9x^2 + 4x + 12 = x^4-8x- 9x^2 +36 + 12x - 24=$$

$$= x(x^3-8)-9(x^2-4)+12(x-2)$$

Answer (score 1):

I've come back to it and, though it doesn't use the difference of cubes formula, I feel this is in spirit of what the text wanted. First, by synthetic division we get the following quotient:

$x^3 + 2x^2 + 5x - 6$

Then by the rational roots theorem we can verify x = -1 is a root. Then we can factor $(x+1)$ out of the quotient:

$x^3 + 2x^2 + 5x - 6 = (x+1)( ... )$

From here I did some brute force guessing-and-checking until I got to the following:

$(x+1)(x^2 + x - 6)$

While this didn't make use of the difference of cubes formula, I believe coming to an expression without relying on long division as much is what the text hoped to guide the reader towards.